# Using Sentry causes strange crash on start

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I'm trying to use Sentry in my Expo managed workflow. I've followed the guide [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/), which includes calling `Sentry.init()` from `App.tsx`:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://blahblah@blahblah.ingest.sentry.io/blahblah",
  enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
  debug: true,
});
```

For some reason, calling `Sentry.init()` is leading to a crash on load. In debug mode (in expo go) I get the following error, which seems completely unrelated:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}).
```

This error is in a hook provided by `expo-fonts`, not in one of my own hooks. Additionally, when I remove the code calling `Sentry.init()` (or set `enableInExpoDevelopment: false`, the error goes away and everything works normally. Of course this means that I can't have Sentry in production which is a problem.

Does anyone know what could be causing this strange issue? I've double checked that my DSN and organization/project name are correct, and that I've followed the guide to a T.

Comment: This is probably a bug in Expo. I'd file a bug on their Github and/or ask in discord.

Comment: What does your Sentry import look like?

Comment: `import * as Sentry from "sentry-expo";`